# can not saveToCassandra in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, hdfs, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I want to take files from hdfs and save to cassandra

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]).setAppName("test")
.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.0.1")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val files = sc.textFiles("hdfs://192.168.0.1:9000/test/", 1)
files.map(_.split("\n")).saveToCassandra("ks", "tb", SomeColumns("id", "time", "text"))
sc.stop()
```

but i cant write it to cassandra because of exceptions

files i get, because files.foreach(x => println(x)) works

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Columns not found in scala.Array[String]: [id, time, text]

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge you can make the below changes

```
var wc1 = files.map(_.split("\\|")).map(r=>Row(r(0),r(1),r(2)))
implicit val rowWriter = SqlRowWriter.Factory
wc1.saveToCassandra("ks", "tb", SomeColumns("id", "time", "text"))
```

**Hope it works!!!...**

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Comment: You need to convert the files.map(_.split("\n")) <--This Statement is for lines you need to write you code for words by giving the exact separator please refer https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/8_streaming.md

Answer (score 0):

`class randomString4File {`
  `val x = util.Random`
  `def create(size: Int) = {
    var str = ""
    while(str.length() < size) {
      if (str.length() != 0) {`

```
   str += "\n" + x.nextInt().abs.toString() + " " + java.time.LocalDateTime.now() + " " + x.alphanumeric.take(20).mkString 
  }
  else str += x.nextInt().abs.toString() + " " + java.time.LocalDateTime.now() + " " + x.alphanumeric.take(20).mkString + "\n"
}
str
```

`}`

`}`
i write files this way